# What is so "potential" about action potentials?

Tags: neuroscience, neurophysiology

When an action potential is propagating through a neuron, it seems to me that the time for "potential of action" is over, and that we are now just in a state of "action". Why don't we just call action potentials "action"? Where is the potential for action when the neuron itself is undergoing action? In fact, when a neuron is at rest, it is said to have a "resting potential". To me this seems more like a "resting state" and an "action state". So what is so potential about "action potentials"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are other meanings of "potential" than the regular meaning "*having or showing the capacity to become or develop into something in the future*" (source: Google Translate).

In case of "*resting potential*" it refers to the **voltage difference** across the cellular membrane. Every cell maintains a voltage difference across the membrane (see a related question here: https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/17840/resting-and-action-membrane-potential). The voltage difference is used for various purposes, including the transport of nutrients and ions, and it is crucial for action potentials to occur.

In case of "*action potential*" it refers to a series of **successive changes in the voltage difference** across the membrane, which occurs when an excitable cell is triggered (see a related question here: https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/91/how-do-the-brain-and-nerves-create-electrical-pulses/110#110).